# How can I write output to text file in C++ by script

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I written a code to create two random number with a given range. I want to write the output result (two random numbers). In script file, I want to write the output in same line for each iteration as my expected result

My current output is

```
1 0   
1 0   
2 1  
2 3   
0  0   //output of second iteration
1  1 
2  2
1  3
```

My expected result is

```
1 0   0  0
1 0   1  1 
2 1   2  2
2 3   1  3
```

This is my full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#define random(x) (rand()%x)

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int time_ui = static_cast<unsigned int>( time(NULL) );
    srand( time_ui );
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int range=atoi(argv[1]);
    number1 = random(range);
    number2 = random(range);
    //std::cout<< number1 << "\t" <<number2;
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("report.txt", std::ios::app);
    myfile << number1 << "\t" <<number2<<'\n';
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

My script file is

```
#!/bin/bash

a=1
iter=0
for ((iter; iter <= 1; iter++))
do
    a=1
    while [ $a -lt 4]
    do
      ./random_num $a
      a=`expr $a + 1`
    done

done
```

Comment: Any special reason you want both a C++ program and a shell script? Why not move the loop from the shell script into C++? That way you can keep the values in memory and only write after all runs.

Comment: The reason is that I can call the random_num by code instead of using terminal

Comment: Your posted code does not match the posted output. 1. The C++ code writes to a file, not to the standard output. 2. The script has a syntax error and calls `random_num` only three times per outer iteration. Remove those discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a newline character that you output in your C++ code, which makes it nearly impossible to "unoutput". I would suggest moving the logic from the bash into the C++ code or vice versa. C++ has options such has setfill which can help you control this.

Comment: One thing you could do is create an array of Vectors. At each iteration, add the numbers to the end of the vectors. For example, since you are generating a pair of numbers 4 times, the array would have length 4. As you   go through iterations, add the newly generated random numbers to the appropriate vector. At the very end, iterate the vector elements to print tab separated, and newline separated for the array.